# Time-based trial for an application - how to check when app was downloaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, time, windows-phone-8, launch

Is there any way to access the time the app was downloaded (or first launched, etc) as this would be of great help in implementing my trial run feature on my app.

Answer (score 4):

I don't remember how does it stand on the Win8 platform, but for WinPhone7.0/7.5 there's a clear warning/guideline in the official documents from Microsoft, saying:

> Do not rely on usage time limited trials to protect your app’s value.
>
> Typically, it is best to protect the value of your full mode app by limiting trial access to key code paths. A user may uninstall and retry an app without restriction so a trial design that offers full mode behavior for a limited time provides only inconvenience as a barrier to reuse.

Source: [Creating trial apps for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Trialappbestpractices)

The problem in time-based trials is very simple: when you **uninstall** the application, the Phone's operating system **will erase it completely**. This means, that **nothing** will be left, not a byte. If you write any data to isostorage, it will be purged upon deletion.

So, if you make a time-base trial and store a "installed date", then the user will simply uninstall the application and install it again, and will be happy to get next free-trial period. If it is OK for you, well, then just be aware of that.

To make a true time-trial you'd need to create some internet service that your application will register to with the phone's/user's UUID, and then the app would need to check at the service to determine whether the trial has passed or have been used up by a previous installation..

What's more, Microsoft Phone Appp guidelines state that generally you should not create an application that "turns off some of its features" at some point of time. This irritates end-users and the makes the whole phone/platform "bad" from the user's point of view, because people don't like to lose what they once had.

IIRC, at some early point of time Microsoft even advised to create **two separate applications**: one free and without the extra features at all, and one paid with all extra features. Later, TrialModes were included in the Market's workflow and Microsoft's App Licensing API introduced a very easy way to determine if an app works in "free trial" or "fully paid" mode, depending on whether it was downloaded from the market for free or not.

I truly don't know which one is most-recent, so let me paste three:

XNA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282459(v=xnagamestudio.30).aspx

SL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.marketplace.licenseinformation.istrial

W8: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.istrial

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to implement a trial function within your phone application, why not latch onto the libraries that MS provides?

[MSDN Creating a trial application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[MSDN Sample code for integrating a trial applicaiton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286402%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

This is only available for WP7.1, WP7.1+ and WP8 (when written for WP7.1)

Microsoft recommends using the WP8 LicenseInformation class, to do

[MSDN LicenseInformation class, WP8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.aspx)

Hope this helps!